# замена значений в столбце по условию

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных, обработка-данных

Имеем фрейм данных

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'фрукт': ['груша','огурец','вишня', 'абрикос', 'груша','арбуз',
                  'груша','банан', 'груша', 'вишня','яблоко', 'груша', 
                  'вишня', 'абрикос', 'груша', 'банан'],
        'страна': ['россия','сша', 'россия','россия', 'франция','ЮАР',
                   'франция', 'россия', np.nan,'россия','андорра', 
                   'франция', 'португалия', 'россия', np.nan, 'россия'],
        'id': ['01','01','01','02','02','03','03','011', '011',
               '011','011', '6', '6', '5', '5', '5'],
        'месяц': ['март','январь','январь','март', 'март','март',
                  'октябрь','март', 'март', 'январь','март', 'март',
                  'январь', 'январь', 'ПРОПУЩЕНО', 'апрель']        
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['фрукт','страна', 'id', 'месяц'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно провести замены некоторых значений в столбце `месяц`:

- если первые несколько (или только первая строка) строк подряд в группе `id` имеют значение `месяц == март`, а далее следует значение отличное от `март`, то на всю эту группу `id`
  нужно в колонке `месяц` указать `значение` , которое прерывает первые подряд идущие значения `март`
- если все значение в группе `id` в колонке `месяц` имеют значение `март`, то значения в колонке `месяц` не меняем
- значение `ПРОПУЩЕНО` игнорируем при првоерке исходного фрейма на наличие значения, котоорое прерывает первые подряд идущие (или одно значение `март`) значения `март`

Как это возможно сделать?

Ожидаемый результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно заменить все вхождения `"март"` на `NaN` и после этого сгруппировать по `id` и взять первое значение в группе, воспользовавшись методом [GroupBy.first()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html). Специфика методов `.first()` и `.last()` в том, что они пытаются игнорировать значения `NaN` и как раз этим можно воспользоваться.

Пример:

```
df["res"] = (df
             .assign(x=df["месяц"].replace("март", np.nan))
             .groupby("id")
             ["x"]
             .transform("first")
             .fillna("март"))
```

результат:

```
In [28]: df
Out[28]:
      фрукт      страна   id      месяц      res
0     груша      россия   01       март   январь
1    огурец         сша   01     январь   январь
2     вишня      россия   01     январь   январь
3   абрикос      россия   02       март     март
4     груша     франция   02       март     март
5     арбуз         ЮАР   03       март  октябрь
6     груша     франция   03    октябрь  октябрь
7     банан      россия  011       март   январь
8     груша         NaN  011       март   январь
9     вишня      россия  011     январь   январь
10   яблоко     андорра  011       март   январь
11    груша     франция    6       март   январь
12    вишня  португалия    6     январь   январь
13  абрикос      россия    5     январь   январь
14    груша         NaN    5  ПРОПУЩЕНО   январь
15    банан      россия    5     апрель   январь
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать сделать так:

```
res = pd.DataFrame()
for i, g in df.groupby("id"):
    g_ = g.copy()
    if any(g["месяц"].str.contains("ПРОПУЩЕНО")):
        g_["месяц"] = g_.iloc[0]["месяц"]
    if any(g["месяц"].str.contains("март")) & (g["месяц"].nunique() >1):
        g_["месяц"] = g_["месяц"].unique()[1]
    res=pd.concat([res, g_])
res.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

res:

```
      фрукт      страна   id    месяц
0     груша      россия   01   январь
1    огурец         сша   01   январь
2     вишня      россия   01   январь
3   абрикос      россия   02     март
4     груша     франция   02     март
5     арбуз         ЮАР   03  октябрь
6     груша     франция   03  октябрь
7     банан      россия  011   январь
8     груша         NaN  011   январь
9     вишня      россия  011   январь
10   яблоко     андорра  011   январь
11    груша     франция    6   январь
12    вишня  португалия    6   январь
13  абрикос      россия    5   январь
14    груша         NaN    5   январь
15    банан      россия    5   январь
```